# Random Envelope Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have tried summing up the probabilities of the [((n-1)!/n!)+(n-2)!/n!..., then subtracting it from 1.  I believe my thought process is wrong it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please note that a good question involves stating the problem, and required context, in the body of the question rather than linking to an image. This makes your question more accessible, and showing this effort will make others more likely to spend time helping you too.

Comment: You might want to investigate *derangements*